# How can i make an app that adding custom emoji to iOS keyboard

Tags: ios, ios8, custom-keyboard

As you know, **iOS8.0** and later allows to create custom keyboard.So i want to add custom emoji to it and able to send them to other iOS devices. Looks like this: [Video Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=35&v=K4Bo6mbmngc)

Comment: you need to implemnt the custom keyboard extension option.

Comment: @Anbu:Yes, i know but it seems Apple only allows to use available emoji by default that it provides. Kindly take a look youtube video i just sent.

Comment: we can customize bro, thats the reason newly introduced in custom keyboard extension option

Comment: honestly, i tried to find out a solution for that but stuck in here. Could you plz  suggest any tutorials? Many thanks!

Comment: see this link may be helps you https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-create-an-emoji-app-for-iOS-with-original-alternative-symbols

Comment: check sample app http://www.code4app.net/ios/Make-a-keyboard-which-support-input-emoji-and-text/52a9ba56cb7e841e178b69d0

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik: thank a lot

Comment: There are a Demo App may meet your emoji requirement in this Kit, check https://github.com/ibireme/YYKit

Comment: @Tom: No, this  respo only tracks keyboard animation.

YYKeyboardManager — Access keyboard view and track keyboard animation.

Comment: might be help you https://github.com/ayushgoel/AGEmojiKeyboard